# postcss-pxtorem the large screen is only half displayed

Tags: css, vue.js

3840 * 2160 screen needed,the design draft is 1920 * 1080,I used postcss-pxtorem,"rootValue": 192,It's normal and responsive to zoom below the 1920 screen.But in the 3840 x 2160 Android phone, the page is distorted, and only half of the content can be displayed. The code is as follows:

```
// design 1920 * 1080
function setRem() {
// Ratio of actual device page width to design draft
const htmlWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
const htmlHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
const designRatio = 1920 / 1080;
const realRatio = htmlWidth / htmlHeight;

let baseSize = 192;
let scale = htmlWidth / 1920;
document.documentElement.style.fontSize = (baseSize * scale) + 'px';

// There is a situation where the width is enough and the height is not enough
if (realRatio > designRatio) {
  document.documentElement.style.fontSize = (baseSize * scale) * (designRatio / realRatio) + 'px'
}
}

setRem();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
setRem();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved, not rem, but Android 5.0 system can't use display: flex;